# query to extract document in array mongodb and php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have a JSON of this form from MongoDB and I want to retrieve documents based on same queries:

```
 {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5281fb3070c68c0c1ccc4f00"),
      "channel" : "1",
      "content" : "8578",
      "duplicateOf" : null,
      "id" : "7420",
      "keywords" : [ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c450500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c570500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c470500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c4d0500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c590500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c530500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c4f0500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c6b0500")],
      "lastUpdate" : "2009-11-16"]
    }
```

I use this query with MongoVue and it works :

```
   db.Measurements.find({ "_id" : 
{ "$in" : [ObjectId("5281fb3070c68c0c1ccc4f00"), ObjectId("5281fb3070c68c0c1cce4f00")] } })
```

but I don't find the way to make it work in PHP,here is the part of the code:

```
 foreach ($series as $doc) {

       $ids = $collectionMeasurements->find(array('_id' => array($in=>new MongoId($doc[keywords]))));
    }
```

Thanks for your help!!!

=====================================================
Found the error!!!

```
 foreach ($series as $doc) {

 $ids = $collectionMeasurements->find(array('_id' => array(
           '$in'=>array(new MongoId(string)($doc[keywords])))));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$in` would be a variable in PHP.  It needs to be a string (as it is in your MongoVue code anyway)

```
array("$in" => new MongoId(
```

This may also need to be an array as a parameter for `$in`, as in `array(new MongoId` *or* you can pass in `$series` perhaps.

Comment: Thank but this doesnt work!!!                                      $ids = $collectionMeasurements->find(array('_id' => array('$in'=>array($doc[measurements]))));

Comment: Your $doc["keywords"] (and probably $doc["measurements"] is an array of MongoID. But the constructor of MongoID does not accept an array of values. You need to construct a new MongoID for each of those elements - if they are not already instanceof MongoId

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
array( $in => new MongoId($doc[keywords]) )
```

You should use:

```
array( '$in' => new MongoId($doc[keywords]) )
```

Use 'single quotes', otherwise with "double quotes" PHP will try to interpret $in as a PHP variable.